# mapping hardcoded config files

Tags: perl, config

I have searched for modules to read config files such as `Config`, `Config::Tiny`, `Config::Simple`. I am not too vague about using those, are there any modules for storing/reading dbi config and usernames/passwords? I have attempted to do this myself, I am wanting to have the config file in a hash data structure for easy importing into my module. Is their an easier way to do what I am attempting or a preferred module that could be suggested?

Example config file:

```
[database]
db=newsdb
host=example.com
user=test
pass=test

[login]
user=john
pass=doe
```

Coding:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;
use Data::Dumper;

# get database info
my %conf = 
    map  { /^\[database/ ? () : $_ }
    grep { /^\w+.*$/ }
    map  { s/\s?\n?\r?//g; (split /=/)[0,1] } read_file('database.conf');

print Dumper \%conf;

$VAR1 = {
          'pass' => 'test',
          'db'   => 'newsdb',
          'user' => 'test',
          'host' => 'example.com'
        };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Config` module is not used to read configuration files, it gives detailed information on the configuration of your `perl` instead.

An easy route here would be to `use Config::Simple`, and then

```
Config::Simple->import_from("database.conf" => \my %config);

print Dumper \%config;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'database.host' => 'example.com',
  'login.pass' => 'doe',
  'login.user' => 'john',
  'database.user' => 'test',
  'database.db' => 'newsdb',
  'database.pass' => 'test'
};
```

Alternatively, to access just one block, we could do

```
my $config = Config::Simple->new("database.conf")->get_block("database");
print Dumper $config;
```

which would give

```
$VAR1 = {
  'pass' => 'test',
  'db' => 'newsdb',
  'user' => 'test',
  'host' => 'example.com'
};
```

as output. Read the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Config%3a%3aSimple) for more information.

---

It gets even simpler with `Config::Tiny`:

```
my $config = Config::Tiny->read("database.conf");

print Dumper $config;
```

would give

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
  'database' => {
    'pass' => 'test',
    'db' => 'newsdb',
    'user' => 'test',
    'host' => 'example.com'
  },
  'login' => {
    'pass' => 'doe',
    'user' => 'john'
  }
}, 'Config::Tiny' );
```

so the `database` portion could be selected with

```
print Dumper $config->{database}
```

which would output

```
$VAR1 = {
  'pass' => 'test',
  'db' => 'newsdb',
  'user' => 'test',
  'host' => 'example.com'
};
```

You can learn more in the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/ADAMK/Config-Tiny-2.14/lib/Config/Tiny.pm).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I must of initially missed over the part of loading to a hash structure in the documentation.